# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "WMIC": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java

I want to get Windows serial number using java code but through exception.
My java code is working on some versions of windows (7,8) and not working on windows 10 pro and throws me exception for the same code (not verified on windows vista).

```
public String getWindowKey() {
    String keydata = "";
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"wmic", "diskdrive", "get", "serialnumber"});
        process.getOutputStream().close();
        BufferedReader input
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("SerialNumber")) {
                continue;
            }
            result += line;
        }
        input.close();
        // String[][] Key = {{"WindowKey", result}};
        keydata = result;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         LErrorDataLog.info("Exception :" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return keydata;
}
```

Comment: What's the error or exception ?

Comment: thanks for reply , java.io.IOException: Cannot run program “WMIC”: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Do you have WMIC command line utility installed ?

Comment: Windows 10 has developer mode. You might have to turn it on.

Comment: yes,WMIC command line utility is already installed

Comment: Yes,Windows 10 has developer mode. I have to turn it on  but Not working

Comment: Did you check that WMIC is on your path?

Comment: Thanks to reply. yes, I added  '%SystemRoot%\System32\wben'  path and  restarted the pc. Now it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I managed to resolve this by explicitly specifying the directory in which the process must run, prior to starting it:

```
List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>() {{
  add("WMIC.exe"); add("diskdrive"); add("get"); add("serialNumber");
}};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().directory(getExecDir());
Process p = pb.command(cmd).start();
// Other code here
```

The `getExecDir()` method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Get the execution directory for WMIC
 * @return File object pointing to the execution directory
 * @throws IOException Execution directory doesn't exist
   */
private static File getExecDir() throws IOException {
  String root = System.getenv("SystemRoot");
  File dir = new File(root, "System32" + File.separatorChar + "wbem");
  if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) {
    throw new IOException('"' + dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\" does not exist or is not a directory!");
  }

  return dir;
}
```